# What does the statement "Suppose that the word size of the machine is w bits and that k fits into a single word" means?

Tags: computer-science, bit

Please I was reading this from the book **Introduction to algorithm (chapter 11 page 264)** and came across this sentence: "**Suppose that the word size of the machine is w bits and that k fits into a single word**", where k is an integer.  I have read that w bits in a computer can be 32 bits or 64 bits but I still don't really understand the sentence above. I will be happy for a simplified explanation of the above sentence

Comment: `word` refers to the unit of data that an architecture supports "naturally". As you said, on a 32 bit architecture, the `word size` would be 32 bits.
`k` is just an example integer here that can be represented by a single word.
The term "word" is ambigous though (otherwise you would not have had this question :)) and people usually refer directly the bit size.

Comment: @Raildex So an example: suppose our k is 7731612445 ,which is 111001100110101110000101100011101 in binary. The length of k in binary is 33. But since the length (that is 33) is less than 32 (if w is 32), it means k cannot fits into a single word or ?

Comment: That is correct.